# How to rotate a 3D instance using an HLSL shader

Tags: directx, hlsl

I'm experimenting a little with HLSL shaders. I have the following code for a vertex shader, it is used to render a few instances of a 3D model. Let's say I want to rotate these instances on their Y axis, and I want to do it **inside** the shader, is it possible? I cannot find any documentation about this.

Here it is my code:

UPDATE: I modified the code so that now the shader receives a rotation parameter instanceRotation (in radians) and use the instanceRotation.y to create a matrix to rotate the object instance around the y axis. It looks like it works, I'll leave it here in case anybody needs it.

```
/////////////
// GLOBALS //
/////////////
cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
    matrix worldMatrix;
    matrix viewMatrix;
    matrix projectionMatrix;
};


//////////////
// TYPEDEFS //
//////////////
struct VertexInputType
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float3 instancePosition : TEXCOORD1;
    float3 instanceRotation : TEXCOORD2;

};

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Vertex Shader
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
PixelInputType LightVertexShader(VertexInputType input)
{
PixelInputType output;


// Change the position vector to be 4 units for proper matrix calculations.
input.position.w = 1.0f;


matrix <float, 4, 4> translation =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    input.instancePosition.x, input.instancePosition.y, input.instancePosition.z, 1.0f

};

matrix <float, 4, 4> rotationAroundY = {
               cos(input.instanceRotation.y), 0.0f, -sin(input.instanceRotation.y), 0.0f,
               0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
               sin(input.instanceRotation.y), 0.0f, cos(input.instanceRotation.y), 0.0f,
               0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f   
                           };

matrix <float, 4, 4> composition;

//i compose together the rotation around y and the translation, the order is important!
composition = mul(rotationAroundY,translation);
//i apply the transformation to the vertex input.position
output.position = mul(input.position,composition);


// Calculate the position of the vertex against the world, view, and projection matrices.
output.position = mul(output.position, worldMatrix);
output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix);
output.position = mul(output.position, projectionMatrix);

// Store the texture coordinates for the pixel shader.
output.tex = input.tex;

// Calculate the normal vector against the world matrix only.
output.normal = mul(input.normal, (float3x3)worldMatrix);

// Normalize the normal vector.
output.normal = normalize(output.normal);

return output;
```

}

Comment: How about passing an array of `float`s the same size as your instance count, and you rotate by the amount specified in the element of that array corresponding to the instance identifier?

Comment: yes this is also my idea, but i have no idea how to apply a rotation in a shader, i just started with HLSL

Comment: How about you start with simpler things that don't require advanced topics such as instantiation?

Comment: :D i know, i was just curious, also i think i understood how instantiation works, the problem is that i cannot find enough informations about the HLSL sintax and examples..

Comment: I think [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509638(v=vs.85).aspx) is a great place to start

Comment: thank you, i have also just found this interesting [tutorial](http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=D3D11Instancing)

Comment: ok i think i solved my problem, i modified my example in case it is useful to somebody else :)

Comment: If you solved your problem, it's worth posting it as an answer and marking the answer accepted - that makes it easier for other users searching to find working answers.